# Is there a collective term for charges & fees?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, business-language, collective-nouns

Say I have documentation of a particular account with both amounts credited & amounts charged(fees). What would be an appropriately descriptive term for the collection of credits & charges(fees)

*(We can assume for this example that fee & charge are equivalent.)*

*update: I am currently using adjustments, but I feel that it implies a mistake in calculation of the balance of the particular account*

Comment: This question can be improved by sharing the research you did on your own before you posted, what you found and why it was inadequate. It will also be helpful to give an example.

Comment: I suspect these are simply called *invoice lines* but I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @ΜετάEd A word to collectively describe an itemized declaration of credits (positive amounts added to the balance of an account) & charges, fees, tariffs, and assessments (amounts deducted from the balance of an account).

Comment: Would _transactions_ meet your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, if you're including both credits and fees in the same document, it is no longer an [invoice](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/invoice).

> **Invoice**:
>
> a bill; a commercial document issued by a seller to a buyer indicating the products, quantities and agreed prices for products or services that the seller has already provided the buyer with. *An invoice indicates that, unless paid in advance, payment is due by the buyer to the seller, according to the agreed terms.*

A more fitting term would be something along the lines of [statement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/statement#Noun) (sense 3) or *account statement*. You could also get away with calling it a *billing statement*.

**Edit:**
Based on the OP's comments below, rather than a word representing a document containing credits and fees, what is being sought is one representing the items in a list of credits and fees which is, in turn, embedded in a document. Such items are usually called [transactions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transaction#Noun) (sense 4) or simply [entries](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entry#Noun) (sense 6).

Comment: Thats wonderful & I agree. However, the nature of the document is ephemeral. A categorical description of the relation of the arithmetic is what I am after. In my particular case the information is presented organized chronologically rather then by description of type.

Comment: @DonGraziano I'm not sure that I follow ... Your edit changing _invoice_ to _documentation_ hasn't helped much. So, are you just looking for a heading within a document for a table detailing credits and fees? Are you perhaps looking for the word _transactions_?

Comment: *transactions* is the word! I couldn't for the life of me think of it. I have been searching all morning only to find terms of service pages for credit cards.

Comment: I don't know any reason why an invoice could not include credits. Like "Fee for services ... $100; Special Customer discount ... (credit) $30; Amount due ... $70". I get invoices like that all the time.

Comment: @Jay   That's normally called a *statement* of account, not an *invoice* (from French *envois*, things sent).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a very similar problem. In my particular case I and looking for a word to classify (and possibly show as a header on a web page) for both Transactions (i.e. from a Bank) and Invoices (typically from a supplier).

The word Entries has been suggested however this is not getting much uptake.

Any suggestions welcome!